# Change UIImage when UIButton is pressed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uiimage

When I press the UIButton it changes my UIImage, and when released it stays like that. What I want to do is when the UIButton is released to go back to my original UIImage

This is the code:

file.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Character;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *TapGreen;
-(IBAction)TapGreen:(id)sender;
```

file.m

```
-(IBAction)TapGreen:(id)sender{
_Character.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CharacterMotion2-iphone.png"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You have to just set different images for normal and highlighted state. 
When the button is not pressed means in ideal state it will display 'normal.png'; 
when the button will be pressed it will change its state to pressed and 
highlighted now the 'highlighted.png' will be visible on button. 
As soon as the button is released from highlighted state it will 
come back to normal state showing the 'normal.png' again.

[TapGreen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Set image for normal state of UIButton
[TapGreen setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
// Set image for highlighted or pressed state of UIButton
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of ways to do that. One would be to listen to both the touch down and touch up events, set your image when you detect touch down, and reset it to what it was on touch up

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```